# Can't solve the math related to power factor improvement

Tags: power, circuit-analysis

[image]
**Image source - Fundamentals of Electric Circuit by Alexander & Sadiku, Practice problem 11.15.**

I tried to solve the math in the following way.
\begin{equation}
S_{old}=140000\angle cos^{-1}(0.85) = 119000+j73749.576\\
S_{new}=140000\angle cos^{-1}(1.00) = 140000+j0.00 \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\; \\
So, Q_c = 73749.576 \\
And,\; C=\frac{Q_c}{2\pi f {V_{RMS}} ^2} = \frac{73749.576}{2\pi 60 (110) ^2} = 0.0161675\;F 
\end{equation}

Which is a wrong answer. Can anyone provide me the correct way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They tell you it is 140 kVAR, so you need to determine capacitance that will provide 140 kVAR.

$$X_C = \frac{110^2}{140,000}$$

From that you can easily calculate C.

Comment: Opps.  I didn’t notice that the unit is in VAR. I did the math thinking its KVA. Thanks.

Comment: You were right, but I still find the text to be misleading: "`Find the value [...] needed to correct a load of [...]`" tells me that the load is 140 kVAr, and that needs to be corrected. Otherwise, I would have said "`Find the value [...] that is used for a compensated power of [...]`". It seems to convey a clearer message, but maybe it's just me (most possible).

Comment: Yeah, i know what you’re saying. But, the load is fully specified by saying any of the following: X kVAR-0.85pf lag, X kW-0.85pf lag, or X kVA-0.85pf lag.